# android cuts HttpUrlConnection posting location in background after 10 minutes

Tags: android, multithreading, service, httpurlconnection

I implemented a very simple service that runs one thread that repeatedly posts location to the server. It works well but when I unplug the device and send the app to background I see that it stops sending the location after leaving the device locked for 10 minutes. (Samsung galaxy, android 6.0) Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
public class TrackingService extends Service {
    private MyThread locationThread;
    private volatile boolean isRunning = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        locationThread = new Thread();
    }  

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        isRunning = true;
        locationThread.start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    class LocationThread extends Thread {
        static final long DELAY = 20000;
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(isRunning){
                try {
                   updateLocation();
                   Thread.sleep(DELAY);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   isRunning = false;
                   e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateLocation() {
        String urlString = "https://api.ourdomain.com/updateLatLong";

        String resultToDisplay = "";
        String response = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(12000);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            String acc = mPrefs.getAccessToken();
            Map.Entry<String,String> tokenEntry =
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>("accessToken", acc);
            Map.Entry<String,String> latEntry =
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>("lat", latitude);
            Map.Entry<String,String> longEntry =
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>("long", longitude);

            List<Map.Entry<String,String>> params = new ArrayList<>();
            params.add(tokenEntry);
            params.add(latEntry);
            params.add(longEntry);


            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(params));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            }

            Log.v("GetRegularLatLong", response);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }  
     }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        isRunning = false;          
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be affected by your code:

```
 urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
```

You should close the connection gracefully with a finally block as [shown here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

```
     HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
     urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

     OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
     writeStream(out);

     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
   } finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
```

I'd suggest to add a log after

```
updateLocation();
Thread.sleep(DELAY);
```

You should also watch the logs to see what kind of exception is thrown after 10 minutes.

Comment: I added the disconnection of the urlconnection. doesnt seem to solve the problem. It looks as if the thread is just put into sleep for no reason. No logs, no exception trace.

Comment: maybe your thread is stuck at the while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }